# Can we have just 4 quadrants in a bubble chart?

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

[In the first graph below, we have a requirement to display just 4 quadrants instead of the numerous divisions, is there any attribute that allows this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T92X8.png)

I was unable to find any attribute that allows us to specify the number of divisions to be displayed in the graph

Comment: Hi @Carine D'Mello, I am not sure what effect you want to achieve, but in general, there is no such option directly for divisions. You need to work on axis units, using categories seems to be a good start. Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hyrwbem1/